# Adding (float) coordinates to graph nodes in Networkx - IndexError

Tags: python, dictionary, coordinates, networkx, index-error

I have a dataset in form of .txt which i want to plot as a graph. This txt provides data as follows:

```
68  57
65  86
67  83
105 156
```

etc, so it's an edgelist.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as py
import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

network0=nx.read_edgelist(r'C:\Users\alexl\Documents\new_python\init_edgelist.txt',create_using=nx.DiGraph)

nx.draw(network0)
plt.show()
```

After these, i can see a plotted digraph which, as I supposed, has wrong topology. Nodes ans edges are correctly connected, but there is no location information.
I tried to import in this another .txt with 3 columns (node x y) for example:

```
2   478909.145  4204244.629
```

with this:

```
coordinates=py.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\alexl\Documents\new_python\nodes_coordinates.txt')
pos=coordinates
nx.draw(network0,pos=pos,with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

but doesn't seem to be working.
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices. <<< That's what it shows in the console when I try to run this.
I suppose it has to do with the fact that coordinates are float?? Or that given by txt they make up a list and we want a dictionary? Afterwards I want to add weights (0,1,2) to the edges but first of all I want to see my data plotted "properly" in terms of topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nx.draw](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw) expects `pos` to be a dictionary when they keys are the nodes and the values are the positions.

Assuming you want to read your input as a numpy array, what you can do is

```
pos = dict(zip(coordinates[:,0].astype(int), coordinates[:,1:]))
nx.draw(network0, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
```

Otherwise you could just iterate over the lines of the file and build the dictionary directly.

```
pos = {}
with open('coords.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        node, x, y = line.split()
        pos[node] = float(x), float(y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your instant answer. I did this but now i get the following:

Comment: networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Node '61' has no position. [Node '61' is the first node in my edgelist (my first edge is `61 1`). ]

Comment: that's because your nodes are strings and not integers.

Comment: You mean the `61 1` txt, which i imported as edgelist, right? But, if this is the case how did it read it and drew it as edgelist in the first place?

Comment: I've added a snippet to read the file with the position. otherwise you might also use `coordinates[:,0].astype(int).astype(str)`

Comment: Thank you, coordinates are assigned correctly to every node.